# How to find max growth rate in a time series data?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, time-series

I would like to know the algorithm of finding the max growth rate in a given time period.

Suppose we have eight(N) data points as following,

[image]
[image]

```
list_x = [84,59,52,71,62,82,45,50]
def find_max(list_x):
   # return the L index, H index, ratio
   # take list_x as an example, L index: 3(52), H index: 6(82), ratio: 82/52 
   # should return (3, 6, 1.57)
   return L,H,dy/dx
```

A brute way would be going through O(N*N), store the ratio dicts, then sorting by ratio.
Any efficient algorithms? thanks

Comment: I don't know how to solve this in a better way, but I think you need dynamic programming.

Comment: I am not quite sure why your expected result is `82/52`. You mentioned that you are looking for `dy/dx` which means that it should `(82-52)/(6-3)=10`. However, there is another answer that is `(71-52)/(4-3)=19` which is > 10.

Comment: Seems like you have to check every possibility - every point compared to all other points. That sounds like nested loops; you can probably fudge on the inner loop and start at the *current index* of the outer loop. Or you could just brute-force it but push the nested loops to C using external libraries.

Comment: The brute force approach can be improved in many cases by putting points in a max heap by y-coord. Then as you process each point from left to right, remove all points from the max heap greater than the current point, compare the remainder to it, and then add the current point to the heap.

Answer (score -1):

As I mentioned in a comment it looks like you are looking for `H/L` instead of `dy/dh` since your expected result is `(3, 6, 1.57)`. Assuming you actually want to do `H/L` then you can try the following:

```
def max_result(arr):
    max_growth, cur_min, cur_min_idx = float('-inf'), float('inf'), -1
    res_l = res_h = float('-inf')
    for i, val in enumerate(arr):
        if val / cur_min > max_growth:
            max_growth = val / cur_min
            res_l, res_h = cur_min_idx, i
        if val < cur_min:
            cur_min, cur_min_idx = val, i
    return res_l + 1, res_h + 1, round(max_growth, 2)
```

The complexity here is `O(N)`

Answer (score -1):

Push the nested loops to C using Numpy.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([84,59,52,71,62,82,45,50])
```

Calculate the difference between each point and all other points

```
b = (a - a[:,None])
```

Calculate dy/dx for all those differences.  This assumes the *x-values* are contiguous and evenly spaced.

```
d = np.arange(a.shape[0], dtype=float)
d = d-d[:,None]
d[d==0] = .00001
c  = b / d
```

Find the indices of the maximum dy/dx and use them to get the values that produced it.

```
max_dydx = np.triu(c).max()
indices = np.where(np.triu(c) == max_dydx)
values = a[np.concatenate(indices)]
print(indices, values)
```

---

```
>>>
(array([4], dtype=int64), array([5], dtype=int64)) [62 82]
```

---

Intermediate arrays - values reflect across the diagonal.

```
>>> print(b.round(1))
[[  0 -25 -32 -13 -22  -2 -39 -34]
 [ 25   0  -7  12   3  23 -14  -9]
 [ 32   7   0  19  10  30  -7  -2]
 [ 13 -12 -19   0  -9  11 -26 -21]
 [ 22  -3 -10   9   0  20 -17 -12]
 [  2 -23 -30 -11 -20   0 -37 -32]
 [ 39  14   7  26  17  37   0   5]
 [ 34   9   2  21  12  32  -5   0]]
>>> print(d.round(1))
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.]
 [-1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
 [-2. -1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
 [-3. -2. -1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
 [-4. -3. -2. -1.  0.  1.  2.  3.]
 [-5. -4. -3. -2. -1.  0.  1.  2.]
 [-6. -5. -4. -3. -2. -1.  0.  1.]
 [-7. -6. -5. -4. -3. -2. -1.  0.]]
>>> print(c.round(1))
[[  0.  -25.  -16.   -4.3  -5.5  -0.4  -6.5  -4.9]
 [-25.    0.   -7.    6.    1.    5.8  -2.8  -1.5]
 [-16.   -7.    0.   19.    5.   10.   -1.8  -0.4]
 [ -4.3   6.   19.    0.   -9.    5.5  -8.7  -5.2]
 [ -5.5   1.    5.   -9.    0.   20.   -8.5  -4. ]
 [ -0.4   5.8  10.    5.5  20.    0.  -37.  -16. ]
 [ -6.5  -2.8  -1.8  -8.7  -8.5 -37.    0.    5. ]
 [ -4.9  -1.5  -0.4  -5.2  -4.  -16.    5.    0. ]]
```